# Sub line level merge tool?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, mergetool

Are there any interactive merge tools that, when they get a merge conflict on a given line, go back and try to do a char-at-a-time merge of the conflicting lines?

I'm thinking of cases where you get a merge conflict between a changed line of code and the same line getting indented.

---

BTW: I'm using [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) called from TortoiseSVN

Comment: BTW: I, the OP, have tried several at one point or another and never seen this.

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't exactly what you are looking for, I have found that using a different diff tool (like Kdiff) will point this out to you much more easily. (They highlight character differences. I have not tried merging in this fashion)

After using this for a while now, I can no longer stand using the built-in diff for Visual Studio.

Some resources for configuring this:

http://www.ytechie.com/2008/12/advantages-of-a-3rd-party-diffcompare-tool.html

http://blogs.msdn.com/jmanning/articles/535573.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
patch -l
```

ignores whitespace.

I don't think a more general sub line level merge is a good idea for code unless it is interactive; if a line you've touched has changed there's a good chance something will break.

Comment: Good point, I guess I should have been explicit on that. I am only looking for an interactive tool.